# Accecing server side variable in Javascript(node.js, express.js, ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Hi I am new to backend proggraming and I am trying to send an array of objects to the client and then the client to add an object to the array.
i am using node.js with express.js and the ejs view engine.

Here is My Code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FVAMRIPCZT8J

The array that I want to send is shapes.

Comment: Where is your code? I think you forgot to put it in the question.

Comment: i know i fixed it now

Comment: Put a [mcve], as correctly formatted text, **in the question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ejs you could do:
put this in your ejs file

```
var shapes = <%=the-Array-Of-Shapes%>
```

from the route use:

```
app.get('/your-route',(req,res)=>{
res.render('your-ejs-file',the-Array-Of-Shapes);//here you are passing the array and the renderer will do the job
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was realy helpful! but when i put it in my files it says [{[object Object]}], any idea how to fix that?

Comment: please choose it as an answer: var shapes = <%=JSON.stringify(the-Array-Of-Shapes)%>